# Trying to see if an email is not a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, email

I've tried to verify if an email already exists in the database.
The same system worked perfectly if I tried to verify a username.
I'm using AJAX and PHP.
This is the file that gets the $_POST variables.

```
<?php 

require_once 'Config.php';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (!empty($password) and !empty($email)) {
        $notEmpty = true;
        include 'validate.php'; 
        if($notEmpty == true and validateEmail($email) == true){
            $password = md5($password);
            $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `Users`(`user_password`, `user_email`) VALUES (?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$password);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }else{
        $notEmpty == false;
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the file that verifies the email doesn't exist on the database.

```
function validateEmail($user_email){
    include '../Backend/Config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `user_password`, `user_email` FROM `Users` WHERE `user_email` = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$user_email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo 1;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        // echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK'));
        echo 0;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Js code(ajax):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    //Don't refresh the page
    e.preventDefault();

    //Collecting data for the server call
    post_data = {
    'email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
    'password': $('input[name=password]').val()
    };
    //AJAX server call to signup.php,which calls validate.php
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "../Backend/signup.php",
        data: post_data
    })
    //Server response and setting the input values to ""
    .then(function( msg ) {
        if(msg == 0){
            console.log("Success, user data inserted. Code: " + msg);
        }
        //Failed
        if(msg == 1){
            console.log("Inserting failed. Error code:" + msg);
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "This email already exists.";
        }
        $('input[name=email]').val("");
        $('input[name=password]').val("");  
    });
});
```

It inserts it anyway, what is the problem here?

Comment: Btw, when the user exists already, it still inserts it.

Comment: 1. Why show us the code for `validateEmail` twice? Is there a difference

Comment: 2. `validateEmail` is a function !! Is there any code that Calls that function?

Comment: oh sorry iil add it now

Comment: I added the file

Comment: @RiggsFolly is that enough?

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Ok,thank you ill add it

Comment: But why it still inserts to the database? @RiggsFolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly ???

Comment: WHat does this do `../Backend/Config.php';`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: All I can think of is that `include '../Backend/Config.php';` does not create a `$link` connetion

Comment: It works perfectly if i try it with a username instead of an email

Comment: The form ```<form action="index.php" method="POST" class="sign-up-form" id="form">
    <label class="lab"><b>Start coding.</b></label>
                <br>
                <input class="input" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
                <br>
                <br>
                <input class="input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
    <br>
    <label id="error"></label>
    <br>
       
                <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"><span>Sign up</span></button>
   </form>```

Comment: Then check the database

Comment: Not sure if this is true but the user contributed notes at the bottom of the [PHP num_rows documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php) states, _"If you do not use mysqli_stmt_store_result( ), and immediatley call this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet."_

Comment: @kmoser thank you! it now works.

Comment: @עילאיאלמלם I have posted my comment as an answer. If it answered your question, please consider [marking it as an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow), thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you immediately call `num_rows()` after executing a prepared statement, it will usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the result set, since the result set is not saved in memory yet. You must first call [`store_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) to buffer the results so that the subsequent call to `num_rows()` will contain the correct results.

This is explained in the "User Notes" section at the bottom of the [PHP documentation for num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#usernotes).